# The place of the caching layer in the service-orientation architecture

Tags: php, symfony, oop, caching, design-patterns

Ok, I build application using three layers for manipulating business logic.

1) First layer solve transport tasks. The layer send requests, get responses and handle network errors. Transport layer call remote API methods and prepares data for using inside application.

2) Second layer is a `Service`. Service is a class (or group of functions) for manipulating specific data from API to organize it in accordance with business requirements. For example `ProductService` fetch list of products then denormalize each of them to object and make sorted collection.

3) And third layer is a `Controller`. This layer is a classic layer from `MVC` pattern. It refers to the service for data and pass it to `View` layer.

As a result we get the scheme of interaction:

`Controller => Service => Transport`

It is obvious that this scheme requires *storing the result from transport layer to caching service* (such as memcached). Therefore it is necessary to add a fourth layer - `Cache`.

**So in what place in this scheme should be located `Cache` layer and which of three layers above should to control it (saying fetch data from cache or get from API, invalidate cache, etc)?**

> My question is conceptual issue and its not require indication
>   specific technologies, however I want to get an answer in the context
>   of PHP and Symfony 2/3 framework.

Comment: The question is broad and depends on details of you services. In my opinion Cache is not the layer, but a wrapper around some layer or a port/contract to your actual cache. It can be Transport middleware if you have to cache some requests completely or it can be wrapper around your service...

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer in a generic way.
When you cache some data, you have to do two things

- When a read request is made, you will first check if the item that you need is present in the cache. If it is then read it from the cache. If not then get it from your original source (in most cases a database), store it in the cache and return the item.
- The other is when you have to manipulate an item. Then you will update your database and then will also replace the item in the cache so that no one reads stale data.

So usually a system would have a common layer to read and write into a database and caching is done around that layer.

In your case it seems that the service layer is the one that is manipulating your objects, so that should be the layer around which caching should be implemented.